# Can I use Eyefinity with two Radeon HD 4650 cards?

Tags: amd-radeon, eyefinity

I have 2 Radeon HD 4650 video cards running 3 monitors right now on my new PC.  Would it be possible to use Eyefinity with this or would I need different video cards?

Comment: I think if you DONT use crossfire and have an adequite power supply, you should be able to use 6 monitors w/ eyefinity. Each card should be able to support 3 displays.

Comment: I am not having troube ooking up multiple monitors, 3 monitors should be enough though, eyefinity allows you to run a video that spans all 3 of them though

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Eyefinity is only supported on the Radeon 5000 series, so you would need new video cards.

From: http://support.amd.com/us/eyefinity/Pages/eyefinity-dongles.aspx

> ATI Eyefinity technology is
>   supported by graphics cards in the ATI
>   Radeon™ HD 5400 series and higher.

Comment: bummer I just built this system, current top of the line everything except my 2 vid cards, guess I should of researhed this more first, thanks for the answer